# Why is food red?

Tags: vikings-war-of-clans

The numbers which are displaying the amount of food I´ve got has turned red; why's that? I´ve got a lot of food, but its still red. Does it mean I'm running out of food soon or what?

Answer (score 1):

Having a red number on your amount of food means that you are consuming more food than you are producing at the moment. Your food amount will eventually reach 0 at some point if you're not correcting this situation, meaning that you will be unable to train any more grip until you produce more food.